# Trying to return info on computer names for test

Tags: powershell

```
    $computers = Get-Content C:\computers.txt #| Where-Object { $_ } 

foreach ($computer in $computers) {


     (Get-CIMInstance CIM_ComputerSystem).Name

      }
```

Why is the above code only returning the local computer name, shouldnt it select the computers in the text file and return their computer names?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot this part. Happens to the best of us.

```
-ComputerName $Computer

(Get-CIMInstance -ComputerName $Computer CIM_ComputerSystem).Name
```

Comment: Thanks! FFS! lol - I can now use this in some more complexity, some times i wonder why i work in IT when i cant do a simple query like this.